# Unable to get correct values with Requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape this page: https://www.checkers.co.za/c-2256/All-Departments?q=%3Anovelty&page=0 but unable to get the discounted price.

Example product:

[image: Product example]

The HTML shows the price of R17.59 under `<span class="now">` but requests show `<span class="now">\n                                            R21<sup>.99</sup>\n                </span>\n`

Comment: So whats your code so far?

Comment: import requests, page = requests.get("https://www.checkers.co.za/c-2256/All-Departments?q=%3Anovelty&page=0"), print(page.content) and I can already see that the discounted value isn't in there.

Comment: The data is fetched async. You can see it by observing the XHR/API requests. The POST request to https://www.checkers.co.za/populateProductsWithHeavyAttributes returns the data. One solution would be to use selenium

Comment: @Nils no way with requests?

Comment: Maybe if you get the csfr token etc.

Comment: Still not getting the discounted value with Selenium: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\jakfo\Documents\Python Scripts\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.checkers.co.za/c-2256/All-Departments?q=%3Anovelty&page=0") # load the web page
items = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("item-product"))
print(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("item-product")[1].text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main url returns only the product ID, name and initial price. In order to get the discounts and other product messages you call POST `https://www.checkers.co.za/populateProductsWithHeavyttributes` with the list of products as form data. The former requests needs header named `csrftoken` with the value of the csrf token located in an `input` on the main page

Also the name of products need to be retrieved individually.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import html

url = "https://www.checkers.co.za/c-2256/All-Departments"
urlAttributes = "https://www.checkers.co.za/populateProductsWithHeavyAttributes"

session = requests.Session()

r = session.get(url, params = { "q": ":novelty", "page": "0"})

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

csrf = soup.find("input", { "name": "CSRFToken"})["value"]
products = json.loads(soup.find("div", { "id": "productListJSON"}).text)

nameDict = {}
for i in soup.findAll("div", {"class":"product-frame"}):
    t = json.loads(i["data-product-ga"])
    nameDict[t["id"]] = t["name"]

r = session.post(urlAttributes, json = products, headers= { "csrftoken": csrf })

productsAttr = json.loads(r.text)

for i in productsAttr:
    htmlData = html.unescape(i["information"][0]["htmlBBs"])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlData, "html.parser")
    print({
        "product": i["product"],
        "name": nameDict[i["product"]],
        "priceInfo": i["information"][0]["price"],
        "priceBefore": soup.find("span", {"class":"before"}).text.strip() if soup.find("span", {"class":"before"}) else None,
        "priceAfter": soup.find("span", {"class":"now"}).text.strip(),
        "discount": soup.find("span", {"class":"special-price__extra__title"}).text.strip() if soup.find("span", {"class":"special-price__extra__title"}) else None,
        "productMessage": soup.find("span", {"class":"item-product__message__text"}).text.strip() if soup.find("span", {"class":"item-product__message__text"}) else None
    })
```

Note that the second request (to get discount info) needs the cookies so we need to use `requests.Session()`